# Detect when a new frame is displayed from Camera Stream using DirectShow

Tags: delphi, directshow, multimedia

I use the following code to connect to the device and stream the video, its works great except I do not know how to detect when the actual frame changes

vars

```
fGraph: iGraphBuilder;
fBuilder: iCaptureGraphBuilder2;
fDevEnum: iCreateDevEnum;
fClassEnum: iEnumMoniker;
fMoniker: iMoniker;
fSrc: iBaseFilter;
fFetched: pLongInt;
fvideoWindow: iVideoWindow;
fmediaControl: iMediaControl;
fEvent: IMediaEvent;
fMediaEvent: IMediaEventEx;
```

Code:

```
fGraph := createComObject(CLSID_FilterGraph) as iGraphBuilder;
fBuilder := createComObject(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2) as iCaptureGraphBuilder2;
fBuilder.SetFiltergraph(fGraph);
fDevEnum := createComObject(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum) as iCreateDevEnum;
fDevEnum.createClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory , fClassEnum , 0);
fClassEnum.next(1 , fMoniker , fFetched);
fMoniker.bindToObject(nil , nil , IID_IBaseFilter , fSrc);
fGraph.addFilter(fSrc , 'Video Capture');
fGraph.queryInterface(IID_IMediaControl , fmediaControl);
fGraph.queryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow , fvideoWindow);
fGraph.queryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent , fEvent);
fEvent.queryInterface(IID_IMediaEventEx , fMediaEvent); // TForm(fOwner)
fMediaEvent.SetNotifyWindow(self.Handle , WM_MMNOTIFY , Integer(self));
fBuilder.renderStream(@PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW , @MEDIATYPE_VIDEO , fSrc , nil , nil);
fvideoWindow.put_windowStyle(WS_CHILD or WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
fvideoWindow.setWindowPosition(0 , 0 , self.width , self.height);
fvideoWindow.put_owner(self.Handle);
fmediaControl.run;
```

As you can see I tried using IMediaEvent and IMediaEventEx, but that only fires when the video stream starting or stopping occur, i need to know every time a new frame is added.

Comment: I think you will need
piBFSampleGrabber.QueryInterface(IID_ISampleGrabber, pISampleGrabber);
with
pISampleGrabber.SetCallback

Comment: @bummi, I think, you're right. user571234, you might take a look for instance how the [`TSampleGrabber`](http://code.google.com/p/dspack/source/browse/trunk/src/DSPack/DSPack.pas#1047) from DSPack implements the `OnBuffer` event.

Comment: thanks! I will take an look and let you know :-)

Comment: Yes that seems to be exactly what I am looking for! Any ideas where I can find a simple example on the SampleGrabber? I am rather new to this side of programming

Comment: I found this link http://www.progdigy.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4163&sid=52c8613ac7dcf73186dd575795a08aef it creates the I Samplegrabber but it doesnt seem to fire the call back procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Video renderers do not report frame presentation such as using a callback. When frame reaches video renderer, it is queued for presentation according to a time stamp possibly attached. Then video renderer decides on whether to discard, present or enqueue the data.

What you might want to do if you absolutely need to know presentation time, is to

- have a Sample Grabber filter connected before the renderer
- make sure that data is decompressed
- strip frame's time by removing respective flags in `SampleCB` grabber callback

The frame will be presented shortly, as soon as video renderer receives it. You still have control before it happens though. If you need it *after*, you need a custom filter that actually delivers the media sample to renderer and on returning control to your filter you know that the frame was just presented to the user.